# Um var, ou let ou const tem diferença de performance para vários?

Tags: javascript, variáveis, desempenho, declaração-de-variável

Já vi inúmeras respostas que dizem que é apenas uma questão de estilo, que é uma boa prática devido ao hoisting, mas queria saber de números (não sei como obtê-los) quanto ao aspecto performance. 
Existe **diferença de performance** entre:

```
var
fruta = 'banana',
pessoa = 'Maria',
acao = 'comer';
```

e

```
var fruta = 'banana';
var pessoa = 'Maria';
var acao = 'comer';
```

Se houver diferença... ela se mantém usando const e let?
Se alguém souber me ajudar agradeço muito.

Comment: Fazendo um teste rápido ([aqui](https://jsbench.me/dyk7eqioqq/1) e [aqui](https://jsperf.com/var-type-comparison)) a diferença me parece insignificante. Eu me preocuparia com os outros aspectos de `var` vs `let`, como escopo, hoisting, etc, pois performance não parece ser o problema nesse caso. E se a aplicação está com problemas de desempenho, provavelmente o gargalo não é aí...

Comment: wow, não conhecia esse site de benchmark! Obrigado! 15% mais lento não me pareceu algo tão insignificante. Sim, numa aplicação com poucas variáveis, isso pode não fazer muita diferença, mas numa aplicação pesada em que cada melhoria faça diferença, acho que é algo a mais a se considerar. Legal ver a diferença entre immediate assign e late assign também. Muito obrigado! Show!

Comment: Acho que esses testes dependem do browser, pois eu só tive diferenças menores que 10%. Ainda sim, isso só faria diferença se o script rodasse milhões de vezes, não acho que essa deva ser a maior preocupação...